# How do relative URLs work in Sinatra?

Tags: sinatra

I am hosting my Sinatra application using Apache with Passenger. It's hosted within a subfolder -- meaning, my main site is `example.com`, my application is at `example.com/popcorn`.

So I have a `get '/'` route, and that works fine. The problem is that my view includes a HTML form that makes a post request to `upload`, and the `post '/upload'` route isn't handling it. Instead of `example.com/popcorn/upload`, it's trying to get `example.com/upload`.

So I figure okay, not the ideal solution, but for now I'll hardcode the form action URL. But that doesn't work either -- making the action `popcorn/upload` fails too. This is where I get a little baffled, and my Google-fu was weak, I couldn't find help there.

Maybe I could have some kind of Apache rewrite rule, but is that the correct solution? Am I missing something? I would really appreciate a tip here because it feels like I've messed up something very simple and it's really bugging me.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the [`url` helper method](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Generating%20URLs). That takes into account where the app is mounted on the server:

```
url('/upload')
```

The above code will evaluate to something like this:

```
http://example.com/popcord/upload
```

Inside your app you shouldn’t need to change anything, this will be routed to the existing `post '/upload'` handler.